# Rails, send push message by parse gives "certificate verify failed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I created account and applicaiton in Parse.com. I want to create push notifications via my rails application. I have installed `parse-ruby-client` gem.

Then in my code I want to send push like this:

```
 Parse.init application_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            api_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            quiet: false

 data = { alert: "This is a notification from Rails" }
 push = Parse::Push.new(data, 'News')
 push.type = 'android'
 # Triggers push notification send
 push.save
```

This gives me that kind of error:

```
 Parse::ConnectionError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)
```

Tested on local machine.

I have read somewhere that it could be bypassed by disabling OpenSSL, but I think it is bad idea in production.

Whad do I need to do?

Comment: Do you use `Charles`? I had this problem before when I used `Charles` on my local.

Comment: No I do not use any proxy services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities for `RoR` to get into this problem. I got it once when I use `Charles`, but seems like you are not in this case. I searched a lot and found a resource listing several solutions. Hope you can find your problem in one of this.

[OpenSSL Errors and Rails – Certificate Verify Failed](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)